# How to implement custom admin actions in non-custom-models in Django?

Tags: django, admin, action

I'd like to build a custom admin action into a model *defined by Django*. Let's say I wanted to add the action "Activate selected User(s)" on `django.contrib.auth.models.User` in the Django admin interface. What would be the clean and proper way to accomplish this?

I had a look at the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#ref-contrib-admin-actions) but it's just about implementing admin actions in *custom* models if I looked correctly.

Comment: I doubt this is possible without hacking at Django core, but I'd be interested to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, YourUserAdmin)
```

Comment: thanks for clearing this up! 

is there a way I could have gotten hold of this information by myself? I searched the docs for `unregister` but found nothing.

Comment: Best way is to read the source (`django.contrib.admin.sites` in this case). I don't know how official or stable it is, though (but it's kind of logical to have `unregister` when there's `register`).